# Converting a Numpy Array Containing Another Array into a Single Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

"x" is a column of a Pandas dataframe. To be able to multiply "x" to a Numpy, "A", with shape dimensions of (2, 2), I transformed "x" as follows:

```
x = copy[["x"]].values
x = np.asarray([x, 1.0]).reshape((1, 2))
```

I then multiplied the transformed "x" array to the above-mentioned array, "A", and added "K" to the result. (K is a constant number=0.01):

```
J = x.dot(A).dot(x.T) + K
```

This produced the array "J", which looks roughly as follows:

```
array([[array([[0.2531513 ],
       [0.25792632],
       [0.2462218 ],
       ...,
       [3.02035684],
       [3.09856273],
       [3.12451776]])]], dtype=object)
```

As you can see, the array "J" contains another array. The inner array has 1418 elements. J:

1. Is of length 1.
2. Has the dimensions (1,1).

I need to J to be of the dimensions (1418, 1). Here is what I tried to no avail (from the forums):

- np.concatenate(J).ravel()
- np.array(J).flatten()
- np.array(J).ravel()
- J.reshape(-1)
- np.concatenate(J))

Can anyone help? I looked through the forums but could not find anything that matches my exact requirements.

Comment: _I transformed "x" as follows:_ Can you provide some more context for that?

Comment: The original array, "x" had dimensions of (1418, 1). If I tried to multiply it to a (2, 2) array without transforming it in the manner I described, it wouldn't work because of the difference in dimensions

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an array of objects, like the following:

```
J = np.empty(1,object)
J[:] = [np.arange(1418)]
J >> array([array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 1415, 1416, 1417])], dtype=object)
```

Thus, first you have to convert it to an array of numbers and then reshape it:

If you want `J` to be (1418,1) then use the following code:

```
np.stack(J).reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Tried. It doesn't change the dimensions of the array, they remain (1, 1)

Answer (score -1):

The solution turned out to be embarrassingly simple. All I needed to do was to slice the inner array from the surrounding array using this code:

```
J = J[0]
```

Thanks to everyone who attempted to help.